# Can I use a USB C connector?

Tags: power, pwm, connector, emc, shielding

In my system, one of my modules operates at 36V, 500mA. I use Harwin power connector M80-8980405 (cable side), M80-8820442 (PCB side) to interface. These connectors are not shielded.

I am looking for a shielded connector. Is it OK if I use a shielded USB C connector? When I googled, found that USB C can handle ~24W (5V * 5A). Since my application needs only 18W, is it a good idea to go with USB C connector? Do you have any suggestions for fully shielded miniature power connectors?

I am also open for any 2 pin circular nano connectors, which are fully shielded. Since space is the concern, I am forced to use small connectors.

Comment: How well can your modules tolerate somebody connecting it to a USB port on a computer, or a USB charger?  Will it damage a computer if someone does that??

Answer (score 3):

I think I have a USB solution. USB PD3.1 standard specifies voltages up to 48V:
[image]

And here is an example of a USB-C connector rated for 48V and 5A:

[image]

Comment: Power delivery 3.1 requires special cable modifications when using the extended voltage or current options.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring any other problems:

Connectors do not have a power rating. They have two *separate* current and voltage ratings. Your 500 mA is well within the current rating of any USB connector, but 36 V is much higher than these connectors are designed to handle--the highest voltage used by anything USB is 20 V, and you will probably have a hard time finding any rated for 36 V.

Comment: Not only that, what is the OP going to do, roll his own power supply with a USB-C connector with 36V on the end of it? How long until someone takes that and plugs it into their phone thinking they are going to charge it? buh-bye phone. Terrible idea.

Comment: 36V is absolutely within what USB can deliver, /if/ you use USB PD >=3.1, that can, after negotiation, deliver 48V 5A. That means you need a USB PD controller in the device, and a properly rated USB C cable. It is not correct that USB connectors are not rated for 36V, though - and it is not correct that max voltage for USB is 20V.
https://www.usb.org/usb-charger-pd

Comment: @MrGerber When did that happen? Last I heard, 20 V 5 A was the maximum.

Comment: It says, right in the link I posted -  "Announced in 2021, the USB PD Revision 3.1 specification is a major update to enable delivering up to 240W of power over full featured USB Type-C® cable and connector. Prior to this update, USB PD was limited to 100W using a solution based on 20V using USB Type-C cables rated at 5A. "

Comment: Citation: 
"USB Power Delivery offers the following features:
Increased power levels from existing USB standards up to 240W.
New 28V, 36V, and 48V fixed voltages enable up to 140W, 180W and 240W power levels, respectively.
An adjustable voltage supply mode allows the device being powered an ability to request intermediate voltages between 15V and up to the maximum available fixed voltage of the charger."

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you are going to make an official USB device or not. You can use it to communicate USB, or negotiate alt-mode for something else, and for negotiating power. PD 3.1 specs allow up to 48V at 5A. You could also just ask 20V from USB and boost it to 36V you need.

If you simply are wiring up 36V and random data which has no relation to USB, then forget it. Since everyone know USB is a standard for USB data and USB power and USB whatnot, people expect that any USB-C interface can be plugged to another for some operation. If you put 36V on the connector or require 36V be on connector, either your supply side blows up people's laptops and mobile phones, or they complain that the device does not work when plugged in with a USB power supply.

So for the same reason we don't use DIN, XLR, or TRS connectors for mains voltage, we also don't want to use mains connectors for e.g. 12V supplies or home theatre speakers, because if you plug incompatible things together just because they share a matching connector, there will be damage.

Comment: Great thanks. My system is a custom design, so no one will plug in their phone for charging. Its going to be just a medium internally to transfer power from one module to other module.. Also, is it a good idea to transfer ethernet twisted 100mbps through this?

Comment: @NICEGUYNICEGUY I'd say no for the same reasons as my answer, but if you are going to use it for custom purposes, the connectors are rated for 5 gigabits anyway for USB3, so I don't see why would 100 Mbps not work, but then again, if you are using standard USB cables, they are not twisted pairs and they don't have 100 ohm impedance for Ethernet but 90 ohms for USB. Please note that there are multiple types of cables and they are not mapped 1:1 but the cables swap pins and they can be flipped in any position on each end. You may damage something if you assume you can plug cables in any state.

Comment: I will use twisted pair ethernet cable, only use the USB 3.2 connectors..